# CSS custom cursor with retina support

Tags: css, retina-display, custom-cursor

I can't find any information about this topic. I want a simple custom cursor with CSS. I have this code right now:

```
cursor: url('img/cursor_left.png'), auto;
```

It shows the cursor, nothing wrong. But it's blurry, because it isn't compatible for retina display. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Thanks, Angelo.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but it should be possible to use [image-set](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/high-dpi/):

```
cursor: url('img/cursor_left.png'), auto;
cursor: -webkit-image-set(
  url('img/cursor_left.png') 1x,
  url('img/cursor_left_hi.png') 2x
), auto;
```

Comment: The reason for the duplicate lines is to provide a reasonable fallback on IE. On Firefox, Chrome, and Safari the second `cursor:` definition is valid and overrides the plain url one.

Comment: Tried it on Firefox and unfortunately it doesn't work. (I think it doesn't read the -webkit-image-set definition, as it isn't a webkit browser).

Comment: Sorry about that; I was trusting the compatibility information in the article I linked rather than trying it out myself. Maybe plain `image-set` would work?

Comment: Tried it, unfortunately no Mozilla support. Using the fallback for non-webkit browsers.

Comment: This currently works only on Chrome. It is broken on Safari in a way that makes it more or less useless: the 2x image is used, but displayed at twice the intended size. https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=120783

Comment: It does work on Safari in the meantime. Even without the prefix: `image-set` is enough. Chrome still needs the prefix. And for other browsers I believe there is still no solution...